# Institutional Login Page on a React Flask App

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, saml-2.0

I am trying to develop a sign in page like this for my app: https://wayf.springernature.com/?redirect_uri=https://link.springer.com

Allowing users to use single sign on services of their home institutions. What is the ideal way to implement such a scheme? Where can I get the ADFS (or IdP) URLS for these organizations to authenticate users on my website and how do I integrate it into my app. Any suggestions/tutorials are much appreciated.

I looked at the incommon page https://incommon.org/community-organizations that lists out the IdPs used by different organizations but I don't understand how to use this information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.